# Set parent height on basis of child height in Ext js

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a Tree inside Panel with border layout in extjs.
This tree is scrollable.
I have height of Panel set to 700 and tree Height set to 650.
Now i want whenever tree expand instead of showing scroller the height of Panel increases automatically so that i have complete tree view without scrolling but by increasing parent's height
version 4.1 or above

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Show us some code!

Answer (score 0):

The align, it does an autoheight by default (the height of you panel). But you can make it stretch to the parent container by adding this in the layout:

```
layout: {
   type: 'hbox',
   align: 'stretch'  //stretch vertically to parent
}
```

An explenation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox-cfg-align)